# How to access batch files?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developinga text editor for java with features like syntax highlighting and intellisense..

I am facing two problems. one i dont know how to read a line at a required index. and other how to use the batch files of java package so that the code written can b compiled.

I will be grateful if anyone can help me.
 Thanx in advance.

Comment: It says "...text editor *for* java", so it could conceivably be a C# question. Leaving the tags alone for now.

Comment: Also, there are two unrelated questions in here.

Comment: @Vishakha: Please clarify the question: 1) explain how it's related to C#. 2) Explain what you mean by "the batch files of java package". What batch files are you talking about?

Comment: please remove c# tag from question.

Comment: @Syed Tayyab- not yet, not sure if its accidental or intentional

Answer (score 0):

1. File.ReadAllLines(path) gives you an string[] and you can access the specific line.
2. The Process can be used to execute a batch. The parameters used can be passed using the ProcessStartInfo object.